# Solution Verification. The number of injective ring homomorphism is the same as the roots of minimal polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

*Claim I am trying to prove*:

Let $K$ be a field and $F:=K(\alpha)$ be a simple algebraic extension of $K$. If $L$ is another extension of $K$ then the number of the maps of $K$- extension $F\hookrightarrow L$ is in $1-1$ correspondence to the roots of $m_{\alpha}(x)$ in $L$, where $m_{\alpha}(x)$ denotes the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over K.

*My attempt:*

For notational purpose, let $\phi:F\hookrightarrow L.$

Recall that $F\cong \frac{K[X]}{\langle m_{\alpha}(x)\rangle}.$ It suffices to consider where $X+\langle m_{\alpha}(x)\rangle$ gets sent to in $\phi.$ Note $m_{\alpha}(X+\langle m_{\alpha}(x)\rangle)=0+\langle m_{\alpha}(x)\rangle$ thus $X+\langle m_{\alpha}(x)\rangle$ must be mapped to a root of $m_{\alpha}(x)$ in $L$. This direction shows that the number of the maps of $K$- extension $F\hookrightarrow L$ is less than or equal to the number of roots in $L$.

Conversely, for each root of $m_{\alpha}$ in $L$, we can map $X+\langle m_{\alpha}(x)\rangle$ to such root and map $1+\langle m_{\alpha}(x)\rangle$ to $1_L.$ Such mapping induces such $\phi.$ Hence, after considering both sides, the claim is proven.

Is there anything I can do to improve with my answer? Also I am guessing the term 'maps' in the claim mean ring homomorphism between two fields (rather than any maps), is my assumption correct?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct, more precisely by 'maps of $K$-extensions' they mean $K$-algebra homomorphisms, i.e. ring homomorphisms fixing $K$. Your solution is fine.

Comment: @Berci Glad to know, thank you so much for the feedback!